# Widgets avoid keyboard but is partially blocked

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue where my keyboard is partially blocking a TextFormField. The Scaffold resizeToAvoidBottomInset is true so the widgets do size and avoid the keyboard, but the keyboard is pushing some entity that partially blocks the TextFormField.

I'm not too sure what the gray box is, but is there a way we can get rid of that to reveal the TextFormField? Imagelink at the bottom of the code snippet.

Thanks!

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 1,
        heightFactor: .8,
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56),
                  child: AppBar(
                    titleSpacing: 0,
                    centerTitle: true,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 0,
                    leading: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Create Activity',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        fontSize: 28,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                body: _isLoading
                    ? Loading(1)
                    : Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                          child: Form(
                            key: _form,
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  describeActivity(context),
                                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                                  selectImage(context),
                                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container describeActivity(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          prompt(context, 'Activity Description'),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borde[![rRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                alignLabelWithHint: true,][2]][2]
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                hintText: 'What do you want to do?'),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            onSaved: (value) {
              _activity = value;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please view this as your reference. There are few things you would like to know,

1. Scaffold should be a top-level widget on a screen.
2. Do not use AppBar inside a body. Create your own widget and display it. As AppBar is internally designed for stack navigation purposes.
3. Widget structure determines the screen behaviour so please review the re-written code to avoid unintentionally behaviours on the screen.
4. Remove "const" keyword below when using Theme.of(context)!

Hope this gives you an idea of how to structure your widget tree.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 1,
        heightFactor: .8,
        child: _isLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    leading: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                          color: Colors.purple),
                    ),
                    title: const Text(
                      'Create Activity',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, color: Colors.purple),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Form(
                      key: _form,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          describeActivity(context),
                          const SizedBox(height: 40),
                          // selectImage(context),
                          const SizedBox(height: 40),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Image output of the code I re-wrote]

Comment: glad to be helpful @ckingprogramming :)